# send post data from jQuery to phpexcel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to open an excel sheet using jQuery, but I also need to send data to that php file as well in a POST. I am using phpexcel class to do this. I have no problem with using phpexcel, but trying to open a window and posting data is the problem.

This next line does indeed open my excel file

```
window.open('boo.php','_self');
```

OK so I tried the following code

```
$.post("boo.php", {
  BANANA: "A banana",
  CODE: "excel"
  },function(data){
    var w = window.open('','_self');
    w.document.write(data);
    w.document.close();
});
```

The above certainly does, open a new page, and it does send my two post varibles, but there is a problem.

Instead of my excel sheet opening it posts gibberish to the page.

So I am thinking that my second piece of code, somehow is inserting something before the header, and then phpexcel is failing.

My php code is very simple at the moment, because if you have a problem, it is best to simplify it.

```
<?php
include_once 'core/bananas.php';
$excel = new globalExcel();
$excel->test();
?>
```

So is there a way to open my phpexcel file and post data to it without screwing up the header?

Comment: What does this function do `vpage()`

Comment: It does not matter. It just gets a page and sends it as a variable. I could stick anything there, even bananas. Please ignore vpage() as it is just a function which hasn't got any bearing on the problem. Basically my vpage function gets the current page so that my excel php knows what to run.

Comment: Well as it is what is collecting the _gibberish_ It could be very relevant

Comment: Try adding the output from a `print_r($_POST);` to your question, that might help us

Comment: Using the browser dev tools, what's the content-type header?  And when you say it "posts" gibberish do you mean gibberish is being posted into the excel file or do you mean the returned page is gibberish?

Comment: Well instead of the excel file download dialogue opening in mozilla, it sends it all to the page instead. So from this I gather that my above code is somehow altering the header. I have change vpage to BANANA to avoid any more confustion as to what vpage is doing. I have already done a print_r, but will check again and get back to you

Comment: Yes print_r($_POST) gives me Array ( [BANANA] => banana [CODE] => excel ) so yes it is posting the data to the new page, but somehow it is corrupting the header somehow. I have to look into firebug to see how

Comment: I think I understand why this code is failing now. You see it is calling boo.php and then it brings back the data, then opens a new page and puts that data on the page, rather than opening an excel dialog download. So I do not believe it will work this way. I can get the excel sheet to show if I use window.open('boo.php','_self'); on it's own, but it doesn't seem to work when I send the data to the page. I am still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I am posting my solution, but it isn't an exact answer to my question. I wanted to do it by jQuery.

What I did on previous projects was to post to php and create session variables and then open the excel page, back in jQuery using window.open.
This wasn't an option this time though, as I needed post variables and not Session variables, as I am calling the same code from 2 different places.

My solution was not to use jQuery to send the information, but a hidden form. So I am not answering my question, but giving a possible alternative solution.

```
<form id="excel" action="boo.php" method="post" style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="VPAGE" value="mileage">
    <input type="hidden" name="CODE" value="excel">
</form>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" form="excel"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Excel</button>
```

As I say this isn't the solution I wanted, but it does work. So I am putting this answer in if anyone else is stuck.

If anyone knows a way to do this in jQuery I would still be pleased to see an answer.